# Is $B_{t\wedge H_a}$ bounded in $L^2$?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $a >0$, $(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a standard Brownian motion.
Define the stopping time $$H_a := \inf\{t \geq 0 : B_t \geq a\}.$$

Then is the martingale $M_t$ where $M_t: = B_{t\wedge H_a}$ bounded in $L^2$?

I'm trying to show that $\mathbb E [ H_a] = +\infty$ and the question says I should use an  appropriate characterisation of continuous martingales bounded in $L^2$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange. Please give more context/background to your question, so that you can get more relevant answers. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @M.Vinay Thanks! I've added a bit more context but I'm not sure how useful it is.

Comment: **Hints:** (a) $M^2_t-(t\wedge H_a)$ is a martingale.  (b) What conclusion can you draw about the martingale $M$ if it is bounded in $L^2$?